# Richtige Beistrichsetzung bei Schachtelsätzen

Tags: comma

Kann mir bitte jemand sagen, wie die richtige Beistrichsetzung bei folgendem Satz aussieht?

> Es wird also nicht alles, was eine Person, egal ob Kind oder Lehrperson, macht, akzeptiert, sondern sehr wohl auch über falsches Verhalten diskutiert.

Ich hätte es so gemacht, was meint ihr dazu?

Comment: Die Kommata sind korrekt gesetzt. Da der Satz so aber sehr verschlungen ist, würde ich eher dazu tendieren, den Einschub stattdessen durch Gedankenstriche abzutrennen: *Es wird also nicht alles, was eine Person - egal ob Kind oder Lehrperson - macht, akzeptiert, sondern sehr wohl auch über falsches Verhalten diskutiert.*

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Gibt es dafür auch eine Begründung, eine Quelle oder ist das nur persönliche Vorliebe (ich frage das als Betroffener der gleichen Vorliebe)?

Comment: @userunknown persönliche Vorliebe, für die ich immerhin eine sachliche Begründung - die bessere Lesbarkeit - habe.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Ich würde den letzten Satzteil ebenfalls durch einen Gedankenstrich abtrennen: *Es wird also nicht alles, was eine Person - egal ob Kind oder Lehrperson - macht, akzeptiert - sondern sehr wohl auch über falsches Verhalten diskutiert.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Kommasetzung passt, die Begründung ist hier:

Der Hauptsatz ist: "Es wird also nicht alles akzeptiert."

daran angehängt mit Komma: "Es wird also nicht alles akzeptiert, sondern sehr wohl auch über falsches Verhalten diskutiert."

mit eingeschobenem Relativsatz (Komma vorne und hinten): "Es wird also nicht alles, was eine Person macht, akzeptiert, sondern sehr wohl auch über falsches Verhalten diskutiert."

weiterer Einschub zur Beschreibung der Person (Komma vorne und hinten): "Es wird also nicht alles, was eine Person, egal ob Kind oder Lehrperson, macht, akzeptiert, sondern sehr wohl auch über falsches Verhalten diskutiert. "

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Es ist völlig iO, eine eigene Antwort zu posten, insbesondere wenn sie im Vergleich zur bestehenden auch/eine andere Erklärung beinhaltet. Daher würde ich den Einleitungssatz in der Antwort streichen und es als eigene Antwort behandeln.